# replacing doublequotes in csv

Tags: regex, unix, csv, double-quotes

I've got nearly the following problem and didn't find the solution. This could be my CSV file structure:

```
1223;"B630521 ("L" fixed bracket)";"2" width";"length: 5"";2;alternate A
1224;"B630522 ("L" fixed bracket)";"3" width";"length: 6"";2;alternate B
```

As you can see there are some `"` written for inch and `"L"` in the enclosing `"`.

Now I'm looking for a UNIX shell script to replace the `"` (inch) and `"L"` double quotes with 2 single quotes, like the following example:

```
sed "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" $QFILE > $TFILE && mv $TFILE $QFILE
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried   s/\"/\'/g ? Or you just want to replace the doublequotes of "L" and inches?

Comment: I just want to replace the additional doublequotes. The result must be readable by sqlloader and some fields may contain a ; as a part of the text :(

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\)\"\([^;]\)/\1''\2/g"
```

I.e.: Find double quotes (`"`) following a number (`[0-9]`) but not followed by a semicolon (`[^;]`) and replace it with two single quotes.

*Edit:*
I can extend my command (it's becoming quite long now):

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\)\"\([^;]\)/\1''\2/g;s/\([^;]\)\"\([^;]\)/\1\'\2/g;s/\([^;]\)\"\([^;]\)/\1\'\2/g"
```

As you are using SunOS I guess you cannot use extended regular expressions (`sed -r`)? Therefore I did it that way: The first `s` command replaces all inch `"` with `''`, the second and the third `s` are the same. They substitute all `"` that are not a direct neighbor of a `;` with a single `'`. I have to do it twice to be able to substitute the second `"` of e.g. `"L"` because there's only one character between both `"` and this character is already matched by `\([^;]\)`. This way you would also substitute `""` with `''`. If you have `"""` or `""""` etc. you have to put one more (but only one more) `s`.

Comment: This looks nearly good. All inches are replaced. But there's still my problem with the "L" and in some cases i've found a "Rest" between the field-delimiters also. :(

Comment: What do you mean with "Rest"? Can you give an example?

Comment: There are other words between the additional doubleqoutes because it's a free-text/free-comment-field in the source-database. So it can be the "L" or "Rest" or "fippel-pippel" or anything else.

Comment: @Karsten: I added a somewhat longer version of the command that should work now.

Comment: Thx bmk. But the "L" and all other (like "fippel-pippel") are still doublequoted. As there's no error on the console i'm afraid there's an error in your sed. 

I foudn this page http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sed+1 and it seems there's a -r option available. Does this help to simplify your statement?

Comment: @Karsten: I made a change to my command that will now work also with SunOS` (at least 5.8) `sed`. It seems that the pipe (`|`) operator doesn't work there.

Answer (score 3):

#### Update (Using perl it easy since you get full lookahead features)

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(?<!;)"(?!(;|$))/'"'"'/g' file
```

**Output**

```
1223;"B630521 ('L' fixed bracket)";"2' width";"length: 5'";2;alternate A
1224;"B630522 ('L' fixed bracket)";"3' width";"length: 6'";2;alternate B
```

#### Using sed, grep only

Just by using grep, sed (and not perl, php, python etc) a *not so elegant solution* can be:

```
grep -o '[^;]*' file | sed  's/"/`/; s/"$/`/; s/"/'"'"'/g; s/`/"/g'
```

#### Output - for your input file it gives:

```
1223
"B630521 ('L' fixed bracket)"
"2' width"
"length: 5'"
2
alternate A
1224
"B630522 ('L' fixed bracket)"
"3' width"
"length: 6'"
2
alternate B
```

- `grep -o` is basically splitting the input by `;`
- sed first replaces " at start of line by `
- then it replaces " at end of line by another `
- it then replaces all **remaining** double quotes `"` by single quite `'`
- finally it puts back all `"` at the start and end

Comment: I've no perl for use and in SunOS 5.10 there's no -o option for grep :(

Answer (score 2):

For the "L" try this:

```
 sed "s/\"L\"/'L'/g"
```

For inches you can try:

```
sed "s/\([0-9]\)\"\"/\1''\"/g"
```

I am not sure it is the best option, but I have tried and it works. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This looks good two. But in some cases i've found a "Rest" between the field-delimiters now. :(